# FileNotFound error downloading roberta-model sentence transformers

Tags: python, bert-language-model, sentence-similarity, roberta-language-model, sentence-transformers

I've already downloaded the "roberta-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens" model, but it starts downloading again and again.
Note: This is not related to space, the machine has space.
And this error comes...[FileNotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbfSM.jpg)

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model = SentenceTransformer('roberta-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! People will be able to help you if you provide all of the details, including the error message. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please include error details, for example, which file was not found

Answer (score 2):

Notice the exception right above the one that you're asking about.  It can't save the file, you're out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/roberta-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
```

If you want to use a downloaded model from disk, it looks like this:

```
word_embedding_model = models.Transformer(model_path)
pooling_model = models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension())
model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model])
```